# Drupal Views Relationship in Code

Tags: views, database

I am trying to write a custom relationship between two tables for Views, and it doesn't seem to be working. The code for my relationship is this:

```
  $data['gov_data_bill']['sponsor'] = array(
    'title' => t('Sponsor'),
    'help' => t('The ID of the sponsor to this bill.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'gov_data_person',
      'base field' => 'id',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('Cosponsor'),
    ),
  );
```

I would think that this would make the column gov_data_bill.sponsor and gov_data_person.id be the keys for the join, however that's not what I'm seeing. For some reason, Drupal still thinks that I want to use the id key on both tables.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post your full `hook_views_data`? Why do you think 'relationship' will work? Did you see this documented somewhere? Also, what exactly do you mean when you say you want to create a relationship between 2 tables? Do you mean a 'join'?

Comment: Code looks ok. Did you clear the Views' cache at /admin/structure/views/settings/advanced?